# How to display non-hierarchical attributes on same row using Excel Powerpivot?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

Using an Excel 2013 ProPlus PowerPivot pivot table, I have the following: (`+` indicating a drill-down point)

```
+Attribute-1
 +Attribute-2
    Attribute-3
    Attribute-4
```

Below is what I would like to have:

```
+Attribute-1   Attribute-2
   Attribute-3
   Attribute-4
```

`Attribute-2` is functionally dependent on `Attribute-1` (they are both attributes of the same table).

If I were using an Excel pivot table to view a SSAS OLAP cube, I would select `OLAP Tools` => `Property Fields` and select the desired properties that I designated as not participating in an hierarchy when I designed the cube. This would allow me to display related data on the same row without a drill-down.

I cannot find the equivalent functionality in the PowerPivot model or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by going to PivotTable options in Excel, Display Tab and tick on "Classic PivotTable layout..." (the fifth checkbox in the image below):

[image: PivotTable display options]

Then change subtotals to not display in Field Settings:

[image: Field Settings]

Comment: Then change subtotals to not display in field settings...

Comment: Note: make sure you change field settings on Attribute-1, not a different attribute